# Upgrade from Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.3 still shows old version in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, composer, composer-update

After upgrading to 2.4.3 (after several issues down the line), the admin still shows the previous version (2.3.4) in the footer, although the CLI version displays 2.4.3. [image: Magento admin shows old version after upgrade]

Here are the steps:

Using **composer 2**, I run:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
composer update -vvv
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean
```

```
php bin/magento --version
Magento CLI 2.4.3
```

my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.3",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Delete your Vendor folder and then re-ran `composer update`

Comment: I've done that - even downgraded the CLI to 2.4.1 successfully - admin stays the same. `# rm -rf vendor/* # composer update # composer clear-cache # rm -rf var/cache/* && rm -rf var/page_cache/* && rm -rf generated/code/*`

Answer (score 0):

Please can you verify this command "`composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update`"

I believe this should be "`composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update`"

Thanks